# Can't connect to sql from php script

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys, 
So I've been reading all the related topics but they still haven't helped my solve my problem. I am new to php, so any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to make an array of customers by using a select statement in php but can't connect to the database.

I get this error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in *script* on line 20. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

And the code:
    $serverName = "*******";
    $uid = "*******";
    $pwd = "*****";
    $databaseName = "******";

```
$connectionInfo = array( "User"=>$uid,                              
                        "Password"=>$pwd,                              
                        "Database"=>$databaseName);   

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = mssql_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);    

$tsql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, EmailAddr FROM Customer";   

/* Execute the query. */    
$stmt = mssql_query($conn, $tsql);    

if ($stmt)    
{    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $stmt, MSSQL_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $FirstName = $row["FirstName"];
        $LastName = $row["LastName"];
        $EmailAddr = $row["EmailAddr"];
        echo "$FirstName";
        echo "$LastName";
        echo "$EmailAddr";
    }
}     
else     
{    
    echo "Submission unsuccessful.";
    die(print_r( mssql_errors(), true));    
}

/* Free statement and connection resources. */    
mssql_free_stmt($stmt);    
mssql_close($conn);
```

Comment: You don't have mssql extension installed. May de you need `mYsql_connect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is generating because you have not open MicroSoft SQL server ddl file from php.ini file.

To make this available follow this steps

1) Open your php.ini file
2) search for  ;extension=php_mssql.dll 
3) uncomment it by removing ";" first
4) Restart your server

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Got configuration and  you have to start PHP_Extension

> "php_mssql"

If it is wamp got wamp -> php -> PHP extension -> php_mssql

Also `php_pdo_mssql`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have mssql extension installed. Also you use `mssql_query` and `mysql_fetch_array` after that. Something wrong here :)