# Php - Call to undefined function mssql_query()

Tags: php, sql-server

I have used the following **`php`** code to show the number of rows from `sql` table but I am getting below error message.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()
             in D:\wamp\www\thereport24\gp.php
             on line 22
```

my code:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('gpcon','',''); 
if ($conn)
    {
    $query= "select * from SubscriberServices where SubscriptionGroupID like 'ms_gp_tr24bn_3333'";
    $results = mssql_query($query);
    $rows    = mssql_fetch_array($results);
    echo $rows[0];
    mssql_close($con); 
}
```

Comment: check if `extension=php_mssql.dll` is uncommented in your php.ini and mssql installed on your machine

Comment: @bigbobr , check if extension=php_mssql.dll ...it is done ...mssql already installed...but i m getting same error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to sql from php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753667/cant-connect-to-sql-from-php-script)

Comment: @Max...i have follow it ...but facing same problem...what is it real solution..

Comment: Have you restarted Apache/PHP? Can you call `php_info()` and see if the right extensions are indeed loaded?

Comment: @GolezTrol....i have restarted the apache/php ... finally i have solution my problem...thnx to all

Answer (score 0):

If you use sql server, use this code. This works for me:

```
<?php
    $serverName = "serverName"; 
    $options = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "Password",  "Database" => "DBname");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";

         $query="select * from SubscriberServices where SubscriptionGroupID like 'ms_gp_tr24bn_3333'";
         $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
         sqlsrv_close($conn);


    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

?>
```

if it returns "Connection established." it's mean you install MS SQL Drivers correct.